# Regular Expression Pattern After Each x characters

Tags: regex

I need a Regex to match the following:

> After each 6 characters of a string there is a `';'`

Examples:

- `aaaaaa;z5z5z5;zdzzzt;` (Valid)
- `aaadzdaaa;z5z5dzdzz5;zdzdzd;` (Not Valid)

I'v tried:

```
(([A-Za-z0-9]{6};$))
```

but it only validates according to the last sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{6};)*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX4iC3/2)

If there must be at least one sequence with a semi-colon, replace `*` with `+` quantifier:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{6};)+$
```

You actually need both `^` start-of-string anchor and `$` end-of-string anchor, and you should not have placed the `$` anchor into the repeated group since there is only one end of string.

Here is the regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{6};)*` - 0 or more sequences of...

  - `[A-Za-z0-9]{6}` - exactly 6 ASCII letters or digits
  - `;` - a semi-colon
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
^(?:\w{6};)*$
```

With:

```
^ assert position at start of a line
(?:\w{6};)* Non-capturing group

    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \w{6} match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
        Quantifier: {6} Exactly 6 times
    ; matches the character ; literally

$ assert position at end of a line
```

Comment: It is almost the same as mine but includes a `_`. Also, in some regex flavors can include much more than ASCII letters and digits.

Comment: @stribizhev I've turned my comment into answer, no copy, I swear. And the OP stated that it was *each 6 characters of a string* thus, I put a `\w`

Comment: :) I do not mean to say you copied anything, just I did not notice any comment and posted an answer straight away. Depending on what OP needs, the right answer may be either.

Comment: @stribizhev let's see what he'll need/choose ;)

Comment: thank you guys , i didn't pick Thomas Answer because \w includes underscore , both solutions are great  ;)

Comment: @stribizhev Congratulations :)

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you. And I know how it should be expressed :)